# Render JSX element based on condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, jsx

So I have a simple component within a web app I have been working on and I was wondering if there is a way I could render an element within this component based on the value of this.props.item.

**here is my JSX:**

```
var React = require("react"); var actions = require("../actions/SchoolActions");

module.exports = React.createClass({
    deleteSchool: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        actions.deleteSchool(this.props.info);
    },
    render:function(){
        return(
            <div className="panel panel-default">
                <div className="panel-heading">
                    {this.props.info.name}
                    <span className="pull-right text-uppercase delete-button" onClick={this.deleteSchool}>&times;</span>
                </div>
                <div className="panel-body">{this.props.info.tagline}</div>
            </div>
        )
    } })
```

**I wanted to be able to do something like this:**

```
   render:function(){
        return(
  code blah blah...

if (this.props.info = "nothing"){
    <div className="panel-body">{this.props.info.tagline}</div>
     }

  ...code blah blah
```

But I cannot write javascript withing the render function itself. Does anyone know how I could do this? Any help or advice is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditionally render using `if` and return the appropriate jsx

```
render(){
    if(something){
       return(<MyJsx1/>)
    }else{
       return(<MyJsx2/>)
    }
}
```

You can chaage your component to:

```
       render:function(){
            return(
                <div className="panel panel-default">
                    <div className="panel-heading">
                        {this.props.info.name}
                        <span className="pull-right text-uppercase delete-button" onClick={this.deleteSchool}>&times;</span>
                    </div>
                   {this.props.info = "nothing"?
                   (<div className="panel-body">{this.props.info.tagline}</div>)
                   :null}

                </div>
            )
        } })
```

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: ahh thats cool, Im just wondering how I would implement this into my component.

Comment: @danjonescidtrix post your component completely

Comment: the full component is shown at the top of my question

Comment: this is great, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Single line example

```
{(this.state.hello) ? <div>Hello</div> : <div>Goodbye</div>}
```

or

```
{(this.state.hello) ? <div>Hello</div> : false}
```

Answer (score 1):

I often create an explicit function to to this, to avoid clutter in the main *render*:

```
var ChildComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
      return (<p>I am the child component</p>)
  }
});

var RootComponent = React.createClass({

  renderChild: function () {
    if (this.props.showChild === 'true') {
      return (<ChildComponent />);  
    }

    return null;
  },

  render: function () {
   return(
      <div>
        { this.renderChild() }
        <p>Hello World!</p>
      </div>
     )
  }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

http://reactkungfu.com/2016/11/dynamic-jsx-tags/

> For many React developers using JSX it is not clear how to make a
>   dynamic JSX tag. Meaning that instead of hardcoding whether it is
>   input or textarea or div or span (or anything else) we would like to
>   keep it in a variable.